# Cleaning up complicated/unreadable if statements with multiple uses of typeof operator

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript object containing which axes data are plotted on.  I need to use this to determine if it is a 2D plot (with data on X/Y, Y/Z, or X/Z) or a 3D plot (with data on X/Y/Z).

The below code works and I believe covers all of these cases.  But it's pretty unreadable and complex.  Is there any way to improve on this to make it more readable and/or simple?

Thanks in advance for any and all assistance.

```
var axes = {
    "X": "Column 1",
    "Y": "Column 2",
    "Z": "Column 3"
}

if (typeof axes.X == 'undefined' && typeof axes.Y !== 'undefined' && typeof axes.Z !== 'undefined') {
    alert("2D plot on Y and Z");
} else if (typeof axes.X !== 'undefined' && typeof axes.Y !== 'undefined' && typeof axes.Z == 'undefined') {
    alert("2D plot on X and Y");
} else if (typeof axes.X !== 'undefined' && typeof axes.Y == 'undefined' && typeof axes.Z !== 'undefined') {
    alert("2D plot on X and Z");
} else if (typeof axes.X !== 'undefined' && typeof axes.Y !== 'undefined' && typeof axes.Z !== 'undefined') {
    alert("3D plot");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use a loop

```
var axes = {
    "X": "Column 1",
    "Y": "Column 2",
    "Z": "Column 3"
}

var axesChecked = [];

for (var prop in axes) {
  if(axes.hasOwnProperty(prop) && typeof axes[prop] !== 'undefined'){
    axesChecked.push(prop);
  }
}

switch(axesChecked.length) {
  case 3:
    alert("3D plot");
    break;
  case 2:
    alert("2D plot " + axesChecked.join(' and '));
    break;
  default:
    throw "Need more axes";
    break;
}
```

Comment: This is pretty cool. David's answer is good too. I really appreciate both of your assistance!

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your code, it looks like just using [truthy/falsey](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/) values could be used to simplify the statements and keep them clear.

```
var axes = {
    "X": "Column 1",
    "Y": "Column 2",
    "Z": "Column 3"
};

if (!axes.X && axes.Y && axes.Z) {
    alert("2D plot on Y and Z");
} else if (axes.X && axes.Y && !axes.Z) {
    alert("2D plot on X and Y");
} else if (axes.X && !axes.Y && axes.Z) {
    alert("2D plot on X and Z");
} else if (axes.X && axes.Y && axes.Z ) {
    alert("3D plot");
}
```